# NullPointerException when getting extra from intent on receiver. Only on Huawei devices

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I found on my bugtracker strange `NullPointerException` in my app. The interresting part is that it only occurs on Huawei devices (Honor 7 and P8 Lite).

So I ran a little test code to check if this is realy an issue with those devices.

Here's my code to start AlarmManager:

```
final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.contant1, new User("John"));
    intent.setAction(Constants.action1);

    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 4882, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

So I run `AlarmManager` to call `TestReceiver` which looks like this:

```
public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = TestReceiver.class.getName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.action1)) {
            User text = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.contant1);
            Log.d(TAG, text.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

All it does is just Log the user name. And here we are. On my Huawei Honor 7 it crashes with the `NullPointerException` but on my other devices it runs ok (tested on Nexus 5, Samsung Galaxy S3, HTC One, LG G2 Mini). I triet with User implementing Serializable and Parcelable. Didn't help. But code runs on Huawei when I put `String` extra or any other.

Someone got same problem as I'm facing now?

Comment: Have you managed to fix this ? I have the same exact problem on a Huawei P9

Comment: Well I had my User object, so instead of passing User into intent i passed his ID (somehow Strings, Integers, Longs and any others worked), then loaded user from database after obtaining id. Ugly hack, but works.

Comment: Did the same, just passing primitive types

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if(intent.hasExtra(Constants.contant1)){

    User text = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.contant1);
    Log.d(TAG, text.getName());
}
```

Comment: This code is just an example. My app in production provides notifications to user about his events. So no - I can't use this, cause Huawei users won't get their notifications.